# How to let cloudlfare to cache the content but make browser do not cache? (so browser always fetch from CF on every refresh)

Tags: caching, cloudflare

Following code tell browser and CloudFlare to not cache the page.
I need CloudFlare to cache the content. But browser not to cache the content.

```
header("Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s",time()+1) . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Use case that I want to achieve is to allow me to purge cache and have results reflect on visitors browsers immediately. (I am purging cache dynamically via API)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this answer when looking up the same question.

Handily there is new way to do this which seems even better than s-maxage: you can send separate `CDN-Cache-Control`
and/or
`Cloudflare-CDN-Cache-Control`
headers.

The advantage of using these new CDN-specific headers is it allows Cloudflare can be configured separately to any other proxy cache that may along the way (separate to a browser). For example if you set `Cloudflare-CDN-Cache-Control` Cloudflare respects that *and* then removes that header from the response. So then your `cache-control` header would be targeted at the browser (set as no-cache).

https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/about/cdn-cache-control

Answer (score 1):

I found answer to my question from following source: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/202775670-How-Do-I-Tell-Cloudflare-What-to-Cache-

It mentions:

> if a customer would like to specify a cache timeout in the CDN which
>   is different from the browser we can also use s-maxage:
>
> `Cache-Control: s-maxage=200, max-age=60`
>
> This will tell Cloudflare to
>   cache the object for 200 seconds and the browser to cache the object
>   for 60 seconds. Basically, s-maxage is intended to be followed ONLY by
>   reverse proxies (so the browser should ignore it) whilst on the other
>   hand, Cloudflare gives priority to s-maxage if present. Note that we
>   will respect whichever value is higher: the browser cache setting in
>   Cloudflare or the max-age header.